# Using jquery to slide automatically depending on different ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dots with different ids. Each id is associated with images. If I click a dot, the images are changed. Now, I want to add slide within 5 minutes to change dot to dot by using auto click function of jquery. I tried creating it many times but couldn't get it. Please help me kindly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#dot1,#dot2').click(function(){
        var id = this.id;
        console.log("id is->",id);

        if(id=="#dot1"){
            $("#dot1").hasClass('current');

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#dot2').trigger('click');
            }, 4e3);
        }

        if(id=="#dot2"){
            $("#dot2").hasClass('current');

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#dot1').trigger('click');
            }, 4e3);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post your html as well.